# Triggering a new event and listening for it

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I am following a book where it shows how to trigger a new event and start listening for it. The event is called channel-25 it just contains fictional data for testing. I put error_log to trap the events process so that i know its working. The event does get triggered but for some reason i cannot listen to it. Here is a copy of module.php

I have commented the section to where i trigger the even and where i listen for it.

```
<?php

namespace Debug;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\AutoloaderProviderInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\ModuleRouteListener;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
use Zend\eventManager\Event;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManager; //manage events (create/listen for events)

class Module implements AutoloaderProviderInterface
{

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }


    public function init(ModuleManager $ModuleManager)
    {
        $eventManager = $ModuleManager->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach('loadModules.post', array($this, 'loadedModulesInfo'));

        //create new event
        $event = new EventManager('channel-25');
        $event->trigger('new song', null, array('artist' => 'Adele'));
        error_log('New Event Triggered');
    }

    public function loadedModulesInfo(Event $event)
    {
        $moduleManager = $event->getTarget();
        $loadedModules = $moduleManager->getLoadedModules();
        error_log(var_export($loadedModules, true));
    }

    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        //Now i will be listening for my sample event
        $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEventManager->attach('channel-25', 'new song', function(Event $event) {
            $artist = $event->getParam('artist');
            error_log('Found the Event. The artist is: ' . $artist);
        });
    }

    public function handleError(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        $controller = $event->getController();
        $error = $event->getParam('error');
        $exception = $event->getParam('exception');
        $message = 'Error: ' . $error;

        if($exception instanceof \Exception)
        {
            $message .= ', Exception(' . $exception->getMessage() . '):' . $exception->getTraceAsString();
        }

        error_log($message);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I moved the Event Trigger to the index controller and it worked.
For anyone else trying to figure out events this is what i did:

indexController.php

```
namespace Debug\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;
use Zend\EventManager\EventManager;


class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        //create new event
        $event = new EventManager('channel-25');
        $event->trigger('new song', null, array('artist' => 'Adele'));
        error_log('New Event Triggered');
    }
}
```

Module.php

```
<?php

namespace Debug;

use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager;
use Zend\eventManager\Event;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $event)
    {
        //Now i will be listening for my sample event
        $eventManager = $event->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEventManager->attach('channel-25', 'new song', function(Event $event) {
            $artist = $event->getParam('artist');
            error_log('got the new song: ' . $artist);
        });
    }


    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you find out the solution yourself. The reason for the code not working is that you are triggering the event BEFORE you start listening for it. In your second post the triggering of the event is done AFTER there is already a listener for it. Which is the correct sequence.

--

P.S: If anyone is interested in learning Zend Framework 2 you can try http://LearnZF2.com.